# SQL - Returning row with the highest count

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to return the row with the highest count and this isn't working. I would appreciate it if someone can help me out. Thanks!

```
(select school_name, count (school_name) as 'school'
  from ad_last_org_info_v
  where ad_last_org_info.id_num = ad_org_tracking.id_num
  group by school_name
  order by 'school' desc limit 1))
```

Example, if School 30 is counted 5 times and School 20 is counted 3 times, the data would display School 30. It takes the highest count and returns 1 result.

Comment: Where does table `ad_org_tracking` come from? You only refer to it in your where, it isn't joined.

Answer (score 0):

```
select school_name,Count from (
select school_name,count(1) as Count from ad_last_org_info_v
group by school_name
) A order by Count desc LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that `mysql` had added support for `TOP`, nor that it allowed the use of brackets to quote identifiers.

Comment: please check i have do change for mysql

Comment: Thank you for you help. It worked! I wasn't sure the differences between sql and mysql, I'm still fairly new to it. I apologize if I got it wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: sql is the language MySQL is a DBMS. The DBMS needs to have support for the functions used (like top)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
select * from (
select school_name, count (school_name) as 'school' from 
ad_last_org_info_v where ad_last_org_info.id_num = 
ad_org_tracking.id_num group by school_name order by 'school' desc) Records
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use HAVING to find all highest school names

```
select school_name, count (school_name) as 'school'
from ad_last_org_info_v
group by school_name
HAVING COUNT(school_name) >= all(
    select count (school_name)
    from ad_last_org_info_v
    group by school_name
 )
```